# How to Filter from CSV file using Python Script

Tags: python, csv, filter

I have abx.csv file having three columns. I would like to filter the data which is having `Application` as `Central` and write it in same .csv file

```
User ID   Name        Application  

001       Ajohns      ABI
002       Fjerry      Central
900       Xknight     RFC
300       JollK       QDI
078       Demik       Central
```

I need to write `User ID,Name,Apllication` in three column in same .csv file (modifying the existing file)

Answer (score 20):

```
import csv
reader = csv.reader(open(r"abx.csv"),delimiter=' ')
filtered = filter(lambda p: 'Central' == p[2], reader)
csv.writer(open(r"abx.csv",'w'),delimiter=' ').writerows(filtered)
```

Comment: This will not write column names

Answer (score 16):

You should use different output filename. Even if you want the name to be the same, you should use some temporary name and finally rename file. Otherwise you have to read file to memory at first

```
import csv
with open('infile','r') as fin, open ('outfile','w') as fout:
    writer = csv.writer(fout, delimiter=' ')            
    for row in csv.reader(fin, delimiter=' '):
        if row[2] == 'Central':
             writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: You don't need to nest those `with` context managers on separate indent levels. Instead, do `with open('infile','r), open ('outfile','w') as fin, fout:`.

Comment: Actually, also note that you're going to need to specify some dialect parameters here. `delimiter=" "` at a minimum.

Comment: I thought OP could do something by himself

Comment: If he copies and pastes your code, it won't work, and he'll have little idea why. You could at least include a disclaimer that he's going to need to adjust for space-separated files - a pointer to the `csv` module documentation wouldn't hurt. As a bonus, this introduces the OP to the habit of reading the documentation - win-win!

Comment: This doesn't really work, it should be `with open('infile','r') as fin, open ('outfile','w') as fout:`

Comment: If I can ask. What if the original file is huge (let's say hundred of gigs)?
Is there a solution that read a chunk of data to memory, store only the relevant rows and then continue to the next chunk?
@Li-aungYip

Comment: @gluz ask a new question and tag me in comments.

Comment: Reference for anyone that reaches this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36132275/how-to-filter-specific-rows-from-a-huge-csv-file-using-python-script

Comment: @pceccon I didn't see you comment before, came to the same solution, suggested an edit and got rejected.

Comment: Sorry, @LiveWireBT, did I reject something? Didn't get it.

Comment: @pceccon No you did nothing wrong. I just wished I had seen your comment before.